# jQuery add html content in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I use jQuery selectors for add dynamically generated html in hidden div, they don't work. How to add something in hidden div with jquery? 
I need to make div hidden while adding content after ajax query, because I should generate many html blocks and add them on page, I want to add all blocks in hidden div and then show all content (make div visible).

Comment: Show the code you were trying to use that doesn't work

Comment: Also provide far more specific problem description as it relates to the code

Comment: @PatrickEvans there is to much code, the problem is - selector not work in hidden div, when it's visible - everything is added, but when i make  $('#panel').style.visibility='hidden';, selectors not work for add html content in it.

Comment: look at errors thrown in console ...  `$('#panel').style.visibility` is not valid jQuery and will throw error. Use `css()` or use native dom node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's hide() and show() function to accomplish this, which is a little cleaner than the .css() ZeJur used. Have a look at my [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ud0qPQHQuntFuRDtYAAo?p=preview)

Example:

```
<div class="hiddenContent">I am hidden div</div>    
<button class="addDynamicContent">Add dynamic content to div - hide while doing</button>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$('.addDynamicContent').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random",
          beforeSend: function() {
            $('.hiddenContent').hide();
            console.log('I hide before request');
          },
          success: function(response) {
            $('.hiddenContent').html(response.value.joke);
            $('.hiddenContent').show();
            console.log('I show after I got the content');
          }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Check out [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ud0qPQHQuntFuRDtYAAo?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

To hide Your element use `jQuery` `.css()` method

`$('#panel').css('visibility', 'hidden');`

and to show it back:

`$('#panel').css('visibility', 'visible');`

If You need to hide your element before loading a new items You can use `beforeSend` function:

```
beforeSend: function(){
  $('#panel').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

and after all Your data is loaded and parsed use `success` function to show it again:

```
success: function(data){
  $('#panel').append('<div>' + parsedData + '</div>').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

and all together:

```
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "sample.php",
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: function(){
          $('#panel').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      },
      success: function(data){
          $('#panel').append('<div>' + parsedData + '</div>').css('visibility', 'visible');
      },
    });
```

Comment: I tried $('selector').hide() and $('selector').show(), and it works for me, but when I add elements i hidden div, their height and width return 0

Comment: The main difference  between `.hide()` and `.css('visibility')` is that `.hide()` is like css `display: none` and when in use there will be no space allocated for it between the other tags, but when `.css('visibility')` is in use the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page.